# How to create a basic JavaScript timer?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, timer

What I was going to do is the user will input a number into a text box, then the browser will pop-up an alert that it will countdown ... seconds. Below is my code but nothing seems to working.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head> 

        </head>
        <body>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                    function timer(){
                        if(document.getElementById("time").value=="")||(isNaN(document.getElementById("time").value)==true)
                            alert("Please input a number");
                        else
                        alert("Start counting down ",(parseInt(document.getElementById("time").value))/1000," seconds");
                        setTimeout("alert('Times out');",time);
                    }
                </script>

            <input type="text" id="time"/>

            <button onClick="timer();">Submit</button>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `alert` is a modal dialog, which stops code execution until the user clicks 'OK', so it can't be used for a countdown like that. You'll need to display the counter in an element somewhere on the page.

Comment: Your setTimeout is going to run no matter if it is in the if or else....

Comment: Have you looked at your JavaScript console to see if you are getting errors? "Not working" could do with some detail, so people are better placed to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `time` variable. It's `undefined`.
Also, don't eval functions inside `setTimeout`:

```js
var EL_time = document.getElementById("time");
var EL_startTime = document.getElementById("startTime");

function end () {
  alert("Time out!");
}

function start() {

  var time = parseInt(EL_time.value); // the missing `time`
  
  // Early return
  if (!Number.isInteger(time)) return alert("Please input a number");
  
  // Everything OK
  alert(`Start counting down ${time / 1000} seconds`);
  setTimeout(end, time);
}



EL_startTime.addEventListener("click", start);
```

```html
Milliseconds: <input  id="time" type="text">
<button id="startTime">Start</button>
```